# Georgian Unicode in PL/SQL Developer Oracle

Tags: oracle, unicode, plsql, georgian

When I do **select for update** and enter Georgian symbols in **varchar2** column everything works correctly.

But result of
`SELECT 'ტექსტი' FROM dual`
 is
 this **`????????`**

, also

`INSERT INTO  test (text)
  VALUES('ტექსტი');`

enters **`????????`** in colomn `text`

NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8

Comment: See [Why are junk values/special characters/question marks displayed on my client?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/).

Comment: My bad.What should I do to solve this situation.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in the topic marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set NLS_LANG. It can be done by changing registry key in branch "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ORACLE", or by setting environment variable NLS_LANG. Value of NLS_LANG should fit the value of NLS_CHARACTERSET - AL32UTF8 in your case.

You could also set property "Check for client & server character set mismatch" in PL/SQL Developer - it's located in Tools -> Preferences... -> Oracle -> Options.

Comment: The Database is not on my local pc, also I don't have NLS_LANG  in  NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS table nor I have the privileges to insert it in table

Comment: @Kostya, the property NLS_LANG should be set on your local pc, where you run PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: The is no ORACLE in  \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software

Comment: Use environment variable.

Comment: In case your Oracle Client is 32 bit (on a 64 bit Windows) the Registry key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE` instead.